# Sort a List<T> by using a passed in function

Tags: c#, sorting, delegates, lambda

I have a function I'd like to write where return a sorted list.  I want to pass in a custom comparison for the objects.  The examples below are rather oversimplified, but if I can get past this, I should be set.

I've tried declaring a delegate of the right type (I think):

```
public delegate int ObjectSorter(MyObject x, MyObject y);
```

Calling it with the right syntax:

```
GetList(delegate(MyObject a, MyObject b) { return a.CompareTo(b); });
```

But when I pass that to the list, I get that there are argument problems:

```
public List<MyObject> GetList(ObjectSorter os)
{
    List<MyObject> objectList = FillTheList();
    objectList.Sort(os);    // Invalid
    return ObjectList;
}
```

So trying a different approach:

```
GetList((x, y) => { return x.CompareTo(y); });


public List<MyObject> GetList(Func<MyObject, MyObject, int> sorter)
{
    List<MyObject> objectList = FillTheList();
    objectList.Sort(sorter);    // Invalid also

    // This syntax DOES work, but too specific.  And why does it work?
    nl.Sort((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));  

    return ObjectList;
}
```

Doesn't work either.

I'm trying to make this as easy as possible for the *caller* to get a custom comparison into the function, and for the function to know as little as possible about the workings of the sort itself.  I'd rather *not* have the caller go through all of the trouble of creating an class derived from IComparer and passing that in.

Comment: ` This syntax DOES work, but too specific` What do you mean by that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx you'll be wanting to pass an `IComparer` implementation to `OrderBy`

Comment: It's not a `sort routine` you're passing in - it's just an element comparer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
objectList.Sort(new Comparison<MyObject>(sorter));
```

Or just change your method signature to:

```
public List<MyObject> GetList(Comparison<MyObject> sorter)
```

[`Comparison<MyObject>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) is equivalent to your `Func<MyObject, MyObject, int> sorter`.

`nl.Sort((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));` works because the compiler automatically turns `(x, y) => x.CompareTo(y)` into a `Comparison<MyObject>` delegate.  When you have the code `(x, y) => x.CompareTo(y)`, the compiler uses the context to determine its type.

Once it's stored as a specific delegate type (e.g. `Func<MyObject, MyObject, int>` or `Comparison<MyObject>`), that is its type, and it will not implicitly be converted to another. However, it can be explicitly converted to another type if it is compatible, as in `new Comparison<MyObject>(sorter)`.

Comment: And that's where I got lost.  "works because the compiler automatically turns (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y) into a Comparison<MyObject> delegate".  So it automatically did it when I inlined the expression, but when I gave it the equivalent Func<> it did not.

Comment: I've addressed this further in my answer. Let me know if that clears things up.

Comment: I would have thought the compiler had enough context from the `Func<MyObject, MyObject, int> sorter` declaration to be able to convert as it did from the `(x,y) => x.CompareTo(y)` expression.  I'm a little disappointed at that, but you are correct it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a function using [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb549151.aspx) for example:

```
private void Foo(Func<MyObject, MyObject, int> sortMethod)
{
   list.Sort(new Comparison<MyObject>(sortMethod));
}
```

Example sort method:

```
public static int SortBytName(MyObject x, MyObject y)
{
    return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
}
```